# Matrix multiplication with each element in third dimension

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, projection

I have 2D image of 3D coordinates (x, y, z, 1) in numpy array with shape of 64x64x4. I want to project each one of them with camera clip projection matrix, with shape of 4x4. I have following code:

```
notProjected.shape # (64, 64, 4)
clipToWorld.shape # (4, 4)
projected = np.zeros(notProjected)
for x in range(notProjected.shape[0]):
    for y in range(notProjected.shape[1]):
        projected[x, y] = clipToWorld @ notProjected
```

This works, but is there a cleaner / more optimal way to do this? I would assume indexing/copying like this is rather slow. I am quite unfamiliar with Numpy. [np.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) seems like it could be used here, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: . . .  Have you tried `notProjected @ clipToWorld`?

Comment: Good point. In my code I added alpha channel at the innermost loop, but for the example here I removed that. I will edit the example to be more precise.

Comment: No, I mean just `projected = notProjected @ clipToWorld`.  No loops needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have `notProjected.shape => (x, y, z, 1)`, using `np.einsum`:

```
notProjected.shape # (64, 64, 4, 1) ?
clipToWorld.shape # (4, 4)
np.einsum('ijkl, km -> ijml', notProjected, clipToWorld)
```

Using the current shapes:

```
notProjected.shape # (64, 64, 4)
clipToWorld.shape # (4, 4)
projected = notProjected @ clipToWorld
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for: notProjected @ clipToWorld.T. Everything clicks now, thanks for help!